# how to send mail using ant?

Tags: ant

How to send mail to a respective user using ant.

I am executing few tests using ant and need to inform the user about the status of the tests executed. So is there any means by which i can accomplish this ?

Regards:
Sachin

Answer (score 6):

Use the SMTP mail task.

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/mail.html

Example:

```
<mail mailhost="smtp.myisp.com" mailport="1025" subject="Test build">
  <from address="config@myisp.com"/>
  <replyto address="me@myisp.com"/>
  <to address="all@xyz.com"/>
  <message>The ${buildname} nightly build has completed</message>
  <attachments>
    <fileset dir="dist">
      <include name="**/*.zip"/>
    </fileset>
  </attachments>
</mail>
```